# Add items to Cart using React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-context

I am new with React, I am trying to do the cart of the app that i am doing and I am having problems sending the items to the cart avoiding to have them duplicate or adding another extra item in the cart. These is the CartProvider code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CartContext from "./CartContext";

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [list, setList] = useState();
    const addCart = (varietals, quantity) => {
        if (isInCart(varietals.item.id ) === -1){
            setList(varietals)
        }else{
            list[isInCart].quantity += quantity
        }
    };
       
    const isInCart = (id) => {
        return list.findIndex(varietals => varietals.id === id)
    };

    return(
    <>
      <CartContext.Provider value={{list, addCart}}>
          {children}
      </CartContext.Provider>
    </>);
};
```

This is the ItemDetail code which i use to display the Item:

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CartContext from "../../Context/CartContext";
import Item from "../Item/Item";
import ItemCountComponent from "../ItemCount";

const ItemDetail = ({ varietals }) => {
    const [checkout, setCheckout] = useState(false);
    const { list, addCart } = useContext(CartContext);
    const onAdd = (count) => {
        console.log("Selected ", count);
        setCheckout(true);
        addCart({Item: varietals, Quantity: count});
      };
      console.log(list)

    return (    
        <>
          <br />
          <Container className="py-5 px-5 shadow">
                <Item varietals={varietals} />
                <div className="ml-4 mr-3">
                    <div className="font-italic mb-4 text-center text-muted">{varietals.description}</div>
                    {checkout ? <Link to='/Cart'><Button variant="info">Checkout</Button></Link> : <ItemCountComponent className="d-flex justify-content-center" onAdd={onAdd} stock={5} initial={1} />}                                 
                </div>
          </Container>
        </>
    )
};

export default ItemDetail;
```

This is the Item.jsx:

```
import { Card, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Style.scss";

const Item = ({ varietals }) => {
    return (
    <>
        <Container className="px-1">
            <Card className="clemmy">
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={varietals.pictureUrl} className="shadow"/>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title className="d-flex justify-content-center text-muted">
                        {varietals.title}
                        </Card.Title>
                    <Card.Subtitle className="d-flex justify-content-center text-muted">
                      ${varietals.price}
                    </Card.Subtitle>
                </Card.Body>
                </Card>        
        </Container>
    </>
    )
};    
export default Item;
```

This is the ItemListContainer.jsx:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import aimara from "../../aimara";
import ItemList from "../../Components/ItemList/ItemList";

const ItemListContainer = () => {      
  const [varietals, setVarietals] = useState([])
  const { categoryId } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (categoryId) {
        const products = aimara.filter((producto) => {
        return producto.category.toString() === categoryId;
        });
        resolve(products);
      } else resolve(aimara);
        });
    myPromise.then((result) => setVarietals(result));
  }, [categoryId]);
    return <ItemList varietals={varietals} />
};

export default ItemListContainer;
```

The error that I am seeing is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

If there is someone that could help me would be much appreciate it. Also, in case you need some extra file let me know and I update the post as quickly as I can. Cheers

Comment: so your question is how to filter out those duplicated items and only modify their quantity for adding 1 each time?

Comment: exactly @tsecheukfung01

Comment: For ```addCart({Item: varietals, Quantity: count});``` ,  does ```Item``` contains all of the items. Quantity is just for 1 item?

Comment: Sorry, varietals contains all of the items @tsecheukfung01

Comment: How about quantity stands for? A single item's quantity?

Comment: in ItemDetail, quantity does nothing, it is a string. In CartProvider I used quantity to in order to create the function, no more than that. thanks for your interest @tsecheukfung01